# Creating nested columns in kdb table

Tags: kdb

I'd like to create a nested listed for one of my table's columns, but I'm unsure of the syntax to use. If for instance I had the following table...

```
q)t:([]submitter:`A`B`C; code:3?100; status:110b)
q)t
submitter code status
---------------------
A         2    1
B         39   1
C         64   0
```

I want to do something similar to below. However this will add the additional column `x` to the table and place the value there instead of creating a compound list for the `code` column....

```
q)update code,:77 from t where status<>1b
submitter code status x
------------------------
A         2    1
B         39   1
C         64   0      77
```

If it were a dictionary with a single value I would do the following...

```
q)d:`sumbitter`code`status!(`A;1?100;1)
q)d
sumbitter| `A
code     | ,88
status   | 1

q)d[`code],:99
q)d
sumbitter| `A
code     | 88 99
status   | 1
```

How do I perform the same operation on a table with multiple rows?

My desired output would look like...

```
q)t
submitter code  status
----------------------
A         2     1
B         39    1
C         64 77 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would also do it for you, doesn't require you to change the type in advance

```
q)update code:(code,'(77;())status) from t
submitter code status
---------------------
A         ,12  1
B         ,10  1
C         1 77 0
```

Comment: Thanks, Terry. I'm unfamiliar with this syntax. Will you please explain the meaning of the empty parentheses after the semicolon in your answer: `code:(code,'(77;())status) from t`? Also, does `status` after the closed parentheses mean the same thing as `where status <>1b`?

Comment: It's using the status booleans to index into the list `(77;())`. Boolean 1 returns `()` while boolean 0 returns 77. So 110b would result in the list `(();();77)`. Appending those to each of the atoms in the code column returns two single item lists (because `1,()` is a trick for enlisting an atom) and returns a two item list (appending 77) wherever the status was false

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the column type of your `code` column on-the-fly like you intend to do.

Instead, you first have to update the type of the column `code` to a list of `long` instead of `long`:

```
q)meta t
c        | t f a
---------| -----
submitter| s    
code     | j    
status   | b
```

Update the type:

```
t: update enlist each code from t
```

Now the type of `code` is `"J"`, which is indeed a list of `long`:

```
q)meta t
c        | t f a
---------| -----
submitter| s    
code     | J    
status   | b
```

And then you can append an element to the `code` like this:

```
t:update code:{x,77} each code from t where status<>1b

q)t
submitter code  status
----------------------
A         ,2    1     
B         ,39   1     
C         64 77 0
```

Comment: I think he should be able to update his current "code" column type to nested list using:
```update enlist each code from `t```